# How to make a lazy loading Apache Spark Dataframe connected to a REST API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm thrilled that Spark allows me to make a JDBC connection to a database table, then build up transformations on it until one triggers evaluation.  I would like to do the same thing with a REST API connection.  That would theoretically provide a way to integrate DB and API information in a logical view.  Is it possible to bind a Spark dataframe to a custom function where the function calls an API using parameters generated by lazy evaluation?

Here is some pySpark code to play with:

```py
import findspark, json, requests
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("basic test") \
    .getOrCreate()

url = 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now'
headers = {"accept": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
obj = json.loads(results.text)
mydict = {k:v for k,v in obj.items() if v is not None}
df = spark.createDataFrame([mydict])
df.show()
```

In this example, the API call is not lazy and is not triggered by the show().

I understand that this could easily be impossible through the pySpark API.  Could it be done in Scala?  Is there a software package which could enable one to do this in Spark?

Could be related to [In Apache Spark, how to make an RDD/DataFrame operation lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494082/in-apache-spark-how-to-make-an-rdd-dataframe-operation-lazy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy calling REST API is possible, but you need to put it in the `map` function (when working on RDDs) or in UDF (in Dataframe API):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> urls = [Row(url='http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now')] * 10
>>> call_time_api = lambda url: requests.get(url).json()['currentFileTime']
>>> 
>>> spark.createDataFrame(urls) \
...     .withColumn('time', udf(call_time_api)('url')) \
...     .show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------------+------------------+                  
|url                                      |time              |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608910925580|
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608911081830|
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608911238454|
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608911550881|
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608911706855|
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608911706855|
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608911863229|
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608912019732|
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608912175607|
|http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now|131879608912175607|
+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
```

In fact, this is really useful to scrap API results with paging - first you create an array of URLs (each for different results page), then you can retrieve the data in parallel inside spark context and create a Dataframe of results.